# Bootstrap and select option

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angularJS and bootstrap.

javascript:

```
$http.get('rest/impact').success(function(data) {
        $scope.ho.impacts = data;
});
```

Html :

```
<select  class="form-control" ng-model="ho.impact" 
            ng-options="imp.id as imp.name for imp in ho.impacts"></select>
```

And i can retrieve the value like this :

```
var dataObject = {
                 impact  : $scope.ho.impact,
                  ....
            };
```

The issue is that when i go on the webpage, the select is empty.

Do you know how i can set a default value ?
like the first item of the list ..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to prepopulate the value referenced by `ng-model`:

```
$scope.ho.impact = $scope.ho.impacts[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a select option with an empty value:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="ho.impact" ng-options="imp.id as imp.name for imp in ho.impacts">
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
</select>
```

See:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: I tried to add the attribue required or ng-required but it does nothing when i send the form. Do i need to add something else ?